# Get the current thread index in C++, to use in thread-specific caching

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, thread-safety

Say, I have a class method which returns piece of data based on the `index`, and fetching these data is quite an expensive procedure. On the other hand, it is quite likely that this function will be called several times in a row with the same value of `index`. For efficiency sake, I want to cache the last used index

```
class DataAccess
{
  public:
    double GetValue(unsigned long index)
    {
      if (cached_index == index) return cached_value;

      ///long calculations to obtain the results
      cached_value = result;
      cached_index = index;
      return result;
    }
  private:
    unsigned long cached_index;
    double cached_value;
};// class DataAccess
```

Now, this function can be called from multiple threads, so I have to store cached value for each thread separately. Ideally it should look like this:

```
class DataAccessThreadSafe
{
  public:
    double GetValue(unsigned long index)
    {
      auto thread_idx = <get current thread index>
      if (cached_index[thread_idx] == index)
      {  
        return cached_value[thread_idx];
      }
      ///long calculations to obtain the results
      cached_value[thread_idx] = result;
      cached_index[thread_idx] = index;
      return result;
    }
  private:
    constexpr unsigned max_theads = 1024;
    std::array<unsigned long, max_threads> cached_index;
    std::array<double, max_threads> cached_value;
};// class DataAccessThreadSafe
```

In C++ there is a method `std::this_thread::get_id()`, but it returns not the index, but system's(?) thread ID. So I would need to do

```
class DataAccessThreadSafe
{
  public:
    double GetValue(unsigned long index)
    {
      auto& cached = cache[std::this_thread::get_id()];
      if (cached.index == index) return cached.value;

      ///long calculations to obtain the results
      cached.value = result;
      cached.index = index;
      return result;
    }
  private:
    struct cache_type
    {
       cache_type() :
         index(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()), 
         value(0.0)
       {}

       cache_type(const cache_type&) = default;
       unsigned long index;
       double value;
    };
    std::map<std::thread::id, cache_type> cache;
};// class DataAccessThreadSafe
```

But searching in map is not particularly efficient and seems a bit of the overkill for this task? Are there more efficient way(s) to match the thread and its order number? Or another way entirely to approach the problem?

Comment: Standard threads don't have an index.

Comment: See [thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: @Richard Critten thank you, looks like what I need. If you can be bothered to write the answer with an example I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: An `std::map` with 1024 entries can be searched in no more than 10 iterations. I find this particularly efficient. You don't?  Anyway, instead of creating a single instance of this cache which lives outside of all threads and then has to worry about which cached value belongs to which thread, why don't you just make each thread have its very own instance of this cache allowing the cache to be extremely simple?

Comment: @Mike Nakis "1024 entries can be searched in no more than 10 iterations" iterations include multiple 'if' forks and jumping from node to node of the binary tree. "why don't you just make each thread have its very own instance of this cache": this is a good suggestion, but the calls to this function are made from various places. Otherwise I could as well include the thread index to the call.